# htaccess conflict in multiple domain

Tags: php, .htaccess

Actually I had a single domain `(example.com)` which is hosted in godaddy hosting account, Recently I bought another one domain `(example2.com)` these both domain I have hosted in the same hosting account.

Now Let i tell you the path for the both the domains:

`example.com in on the / folder`
`example2.com in on the /example2 folder`

I have created 3 sub-domains with my `example.com` domain and the hosting account created the folder for the same sub-domains on the the / directory.

lets say `demo.example.com` and the folder is `/demo`

Now come to the second domain, recently i have created a sub-domain for my `example2.com`

that is `test.example2.com` which is located on the root with the folder `/test` not like `/example2/test` because my second domain is in the `/example2` folder

Now the problem is when I enable the .htaccess file for my `test.example2.com` I got the

`500 Internal Server Error`

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

ErrorDocument 404 /404error.php

Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost
RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(all)/([^/]+)/?$ story.php?title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(all)/?$ index.php [R=301,L]
```

here is a bit part of the `.htaccess` file but without htaccess it's working fine, I think I have problem with the `RewriteBase`

I also tried with like `RewriteBase /test/`

and `RewriteBase /example2/test/`

but didn't helpful, can anyone tell me where is the problem, and how do I debug this problem?

but rest of this my other sub-domain working fine.

**UPDATE ERROR LOG**

```
[Tue Oct 16 21:47:04 2012] [alert] [client 110.172.129.110] /var/chroot/home/content/06/8871106/html/bestsocialbookmark/.htaccess: Option All not allowed here
[Tue Oct 16 21:47:07 2012] [alert] [client 110.172.129.110] /var/chroot/home/content/06/8871106/html/bestsocialbookmark/.htaccess: Option All not allowed here
```

being true, I don't know what it's mean.

Comment: What URL are you going to that's causing 500 error? (e.g. `http://test.example2.com/...`)

Comment: @JonLin the url is `http://test/example2.com` i got the the 500 error.

Comment: `http://test/example2.com`?  I don't get it. Do you mean `http://test.example2.com/`?

Comment: @JonLin OOPs sorry yes, `http://test.example2.com/`

Comment: You have anything in the error logs?

Comment: @JonLin i have updated my question with one of the error LOG.

Comment: Those look like access logs, error logs (usually ends with `error_log`) tell you *why* you got a 500 error

Comment: @JonLin i have updated the error log file now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /var/chroot/home/content/06/8871106/html/bestsocialbookmark/.htaccess: Option All not allowed here

This is probably what's causing the error. And not your rules (which look fine, they work ok for me in a blank htaccess file).

So somwhere in the htaccess file in the `/var/chroot/home/content/06/8871106/html/bestsocialbookmark/` directory, you have an `Option All` somewhere. You probably mean `Options All`, since `Option` isn't a core directive (it could be used in another 3rd party module or something, but apparently it's not allowed). Just remove it.

Comment: here is the complete .htaccess file http://scrp.at/bQz, can you please help me to find out, cause i got `Options All` and i tried without it, but not helpful..

Comment: @jogesh_p Line 220, `Options All`

Comment: wow, working now, i forgot to set the actual `RewriteBase /`. Thanks a log man. +1 i got a new way to debug the problem ;)